# What makes the folder associated with Word or Powerpoint HTML files special?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, html

When Word or Powerpoint saves a file as HTML, it creates a filename.htm file, and a filename_files folder.

What makes this combination of file and folder special? If I delete one, the other is also deleted. If I move one, the other gets moved.

Some of my coworkers will try to be helpful, and edit a HTML file with Word, and it creates the *_files folder. I can clean up, or restore a previous version of the .htm file, but can't remove the folder. What gives?

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: My computer has Windows XP, with Office 2007. However, I'm not in a homogeneous environment.

Comment: I removed the office tags, since your question is not specific to Office (happens also with IE „Save as…” feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only speeial thing on the folders is the name.

Go ahead and create an HTML file called "xyzt.html". Then create (in Windows explorer) a folder with the name "xyzt_files". Now if you move the xyzt.html, Windows Explorer will also move the xyzt_files folder.

This is a behaviour of the Windowds Explorer, as if you move the xyzt.html from the command line, the xyzt_files folder will not be moved.

Answer (score 2):

In Control Panel>Folder Options, click the View tab, and under „Management of pair of folders and webpages” click „Show both parts and manage them separately”. Don’t know the exact wording, using Polish version of Windows.

Comment: @daxlerod why didn’t you accept my answer?

Comment: The question was "What makes the folder special?" While your answer was helpful, it really answers a different question.

Comment: @daxlerod I read that as a problem with removing the folder.